# Partial derivative of sample standard deviation w.r.t individual data points

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative, standard-deviation

I would like to derive the partial derivative  $\delta f \,/ \, \delta x_j $ for

$$
f(x_1,x_2,...,x_{j-1},x_j,x_{j+1},...,x_n)=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n-1}}
$$

which is the partial derivative of the sample standard deviation with respect to a specific data point $x_j$.

Using the chain rule of differentiation:

$$
\frac{\delta f}{\delta x_j}=\frac{\delta f}{\delta u}\frac{\delta u}{\delta x_j}
$$

$$
u=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n-1}
$$

$$
\frac{\delta f}{\delta u}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}
$$
$$
\frac{\delta u}{\delta x_j}=\frac{2}{n-1} \Bigl( \frac{x_j}{n}-\bar{x} \Bigr)
$$
$$
\frac{\delta f}{\delta x_j} = \frac{\frac{1}{n-1}(\frac{x_j}{n}-\bar{x})}{s}
$$

where $s$ is the sample standard deviation itself.

However, I think this is incorrect. In a simple example: $x_1=1, x_2=2, x_3=3$, then my estimate of $\delta f \,/ \, \delta x_j $ is always negative. It seems to me that $\delta f \,/ \, \delta x_3 $ should be positive.

Does anyone know where I might have messed up?

In the working out for $\delta u / \delta x_j$ (below) I tried to separate the $x_j$ and non-$x_j$ terms before differentiating with respect to $x_j$.

Can anyone see what went wrong? I can't see any mistakes.

EDIT: Working out for $\delta u / \delta x_j$:
$$
u=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n-1} \\
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Bigl( x_i - \frac{x_j}{n} - (\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_{j-1}+x_{j+1}+...x_n}{n})\Bigr)^2}{n-1} \\
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \Bigl((x_i-\frac{x_j}{n}-C)(x_i-\frac{x_j}{n}-C)\Bigr)}{n-1} \\
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \Bigl(x_i^2 - 2\frac{x_i x_j}{n} - 2Cx_i + 2C\frac{x_j}{n} + \frac{x_j^2}{n^2} + C^2\Bigr)}{n-1}\\
=\frac{x_j^2-2Cx_j + n2C\frac{x_j}{n}+n\frac{x_j^2}{n^2}-2x_j \bar{x} + Z}{n-1} \\
\Bigl[note: \sum_{i=0}^{n}-2\frac{x_i x_j}{n} = -2x_j \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{x_i}{n}=-2x_j\bar{x} \Bigr]\\
[C \text{ and } Z \text{ are supposed to be all the non-}x_j\text{ terms]}\\
=\frac{x_j^2+\frac{x_j^2}{n}-2x_j \bar{x}+Z}{n-1}\\
\frac{\delta u}{\delta x_j} = \frac{\Bigl( 2x_j + \frac{2}{n}x_j - 2(\bar{x}+x_j )\Bigr)}{n-1}\\
=\frac{2}{n-1}\Bigl(x_j + \frac{x_j}{n} - \bar{x} - x_j \Bigr)\\
=\frac{2}{n-1}\Bigl( \frac{x_j}{n}-\bar{x} \Bigr)
$$

Comment: Hi, why is $u$ divided by $n$ in the expression of $\partial u / \partial x_j$? I think this may be the mistake.

Comment: Hmm, I will check my working and get back to you! Thanks

Comment: Hey @Pohoua, I checked my workings for $\delta u / \delta x_j$ and still came to the same answer (see Edits) :(. Can you see any problem with it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late answer!

I got $\frac{\delta u}{\delta x_j} = \frac2{n-1}(x_j - \overline{x}) $.

And for $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x_j} = \frac{x_j-\overline{x}}{(n-1)s} $

It seems like this formula agrees with sympy for your example.

```
import sympy

x1, x2, x3 = sympy.symbols('x1 x2 x3')
mean = (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3

sigma2 = ((x1 - mean)**2 + (x2 - mean)**2 + (x3 - mean)**2) / (3 - 1)
sympy.diff(sigma2, x1)
```

$\frac{2x_1}{3} -\frac{x_2}3 - \frac{x_3}3$

$\frac{\delta \sigma^2}{\delta x_j} = \frac2{n-1}(x_j-\overline{x}) = \frac{2x_1}{3} -\frac{x_2}3 - \frac{x_3}3$

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result as Темирлан Биджиев.

Here is the derivation. I am just using $N$ instead of $N-1$ and $y$ instead of $x$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \bar{y})^2} \\
=& \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \bar{y})^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{N} \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \bar{y})^2 \\
=& \frac{1}{2 \sigma_y} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} \left( y_i - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N y_j \right) ^2 \\
=& \frac{1}{2 N \sigma_y} \sum_{i=1}^N 2 \left( y_i - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N y_j \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} \left( y_i - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N y_j \right) \\
=& \frac{1}{N\sigma_y} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^N \left( y_i - \bar{y} \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} \left( y_i - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N y_j \right) \right] \\
=& \frac{1}{N\sigma_y} \left[ \left( \sum_{i \neq l} \left( y_i - \bar{y} \right) \left( -\frac{1}{N} \right) \right) + (y_l - \bar{y}) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{N} \right) \right] \\
=& \frac{1}{N\sigma_y} \left[ \left( \sum_{i \neq l} \frac{\bar{y}}{N} - \frac{y_i}{N} \right) + y_l - \frac{y_l}{N} - \bar{y} + \frac{\bar{y}}{N} \right] \\
=& \frac{1}{N\sigma_y} \left[ y_l - \bar{y} + \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{\bar{y}}{N} - \frac{y_i}{N} \right) \right] \\
=& \frac{1}{N\sigma_y} \left[ y_l - \bar{y} + \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \bar{y} -  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right] \\
=& \frac{1}{N\sigma_y} \left[ y_l - \bar{y} + \bar{y} - \bar{y} \right] \\
=& \frac{y_l - \bar{y}}{N\sigma_y} \\
\end{aligned}
$$